# Pi not auto mounting exfat drive on boot, despite fstab entry

Tags: boot, boot-issues, mount, fstab

I'm trying to get my usb drive to auto mount and Ive been following countless guides and threads on it but I still can't get it to work, using fstab.

I wasn't even able to boot until I added `nofail`, which lets me boot but doesn't mount the drive.

My fstab entry is:
`UUID=my-uid /media/pi/drive-name exfat-fuse uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=0022,sync,auto,nofail,rw 0 0`

Has anyone got any suggestions on what the issue may be?

Comment: Try just 'exfat' instead of 'exfat-fuse'. I'm going to assume you've installed exfat-fuse in the first place!

Comment: @recantha that seems to have done it! Thank you very much.

Comment: Let's put that as an answer then... :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use 'exfat' instead of 'exfat-fuse' in the fstab entry. This should make it work with exfat-fuse. The assumption is that you've already installed exfat-fuse.

Answer (score -1):

Wrong !
Use fuseblk
Example: /dev/sdb1 on /media/usb1 type fuseblk (rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096)

Kind Regards,

Gilles

Comment: What is wrong? I cannot find a statement in the question that could be stated as "wrong". Please explain a bit more in detail what you mean. And please take the short [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to get an idea how things work here.